# tailwind style 2 divs next and underneath each other

Tags: css, tailwind-css

This is my first time working with Tailwind CSS, and I'm wondering how I could align my divs differently.

I currently show my divs in the center of the page, one underneath another, but I would like to show them alongside each other.

How would I manage to do this?

```
<template>
  <div class="grid grid-cols-1 pt-8 w-1/4">
    <div class="flex flex-col w-full p-6 items-center gap-8 rounded-md border-[1px] border-border_sm bg-zinc-800 text-white">
      <a :href="#">
        <img class="w-full rounded-md" src="https://aniketkotal.me/_nuxt/hanako.5b94cb52.jpg">
      </a>
      <div class="flex flex-col gap-4">
        <p class="text-lg">
          name
      </p>

        <p class="md:text-base">
          description
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    project: {
      default: null,
      type: Object,
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

What my styling looks like now:

[image]

How I want it to look:

[image]

Comment: While I don't find [Tailwind's documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/) as intuitive as that of jQuery, it's still probably worth looking at that documentation (I'm not criticising the question, since it should be of use to future visitors), but it's not all that hard to find the information on their site: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/grid-template-columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing `grid-cols-1` -> `grid-cols-2` would fix it